# Rendering image issue in IE8 only

Tags: css, image, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I am trying to work out what is going on with regards to rendering this image in MS IE8 only as from the looks of it, it seems to render fine with other browsers (FF, Chrome, Safari)

I unfortunately do not have IE8 handy as I am on a Mac, but have been using Adobe BrowserLab.

I am hoping to correct the rendering of this image in IE8 without affecting the other browsers, where it currently works.

Comment: The only evidence of the problem in this old question was a link to `http://mowjoes.com.au/contact-us/`, which is now not accessible (I have removed it). Thus, the question is missing a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have IE8 handy either, but IE8 doesn't support background-size and the image is 1905x922px. Try resizing it to 500px wide (the size of the element), removing background-size, and seeing if it works.

Comment: Thanks - didn't realise my image was that size. Missed this one during my development. Anyways, that solved my problem. Thanks again.